# Java enum giving an error?

Tags: java, enums

When I try to give a value to my enum, it gives me this error:

constructor status in enum status cannot be applied to given types; STATUS_OPEN(0),

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is my code thus far:

```
 public enum Status 
 { 
     STATUS_OPEN(0),  
     STATUS_STARTED(1),  
     STATUS_INPROGRESS(2),  
     STATUS_ONHOLD(3),  
     STATUS_COMPLETED(4),  
     STATUS_CLOSED(5);  

 }
```

I'm using notepad and the JDK via command prompt - I don't want to use netbeans or eclipse at the moment.

I was following this site: [link](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/07/08/enums-in-java-5-code-examples.html)

I've googled around and I couldn't really find why this issue is occurring or how to fix it by searching for the error.

Comment: Thos values are the default values of the ordinal of the enum. You could remove them, and use ordinal() to get the same value.

Comment: hmm yea, i did read that... i don't actually want to start at 0 though (i was just testing it out), i'd like to start at 1. but thanks :)

Comment: You could increment them when you get them......... Ok, I'm kidding :P

Comment: @EvertonAgner Lol! Ahah, thanks, i'll try that out ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need  to add a constructor to the enum.

```
public enum Status {
   STATUS_OPEN(0),  
   STATUS_STARTED(1),  
   STATUS_INPROGRESS(2),  
   STATUS_ONHOLD(3),  
   STATUS_COMPLETED(4),
   STATUS_CLOSED(5);

   private final int number;
   Status(int number) { 
       this.number = number;
   }

   public int getMagicNumber() { return number; } 
}
```

This'll fix your syntax problems, but what are you hoping to achieve with the number?  Enums are often used instead of the need for numbers at all.

Comment: And at least getter to check the number from outside.

Comment: Ok. i still get multiple errors though. It says constructor Status in enum cannot be applied ti given types STATUS_OPEN(0) etc... same error for each one...

Comment: Ohhh nevermind, i was doing something else wrong. And hence it was giving those errors. I see now. Okay, thanks!

Comment: @ Peter Gwiazda, i'll make sure to add that in, thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to `declare` the `status instance variable` and `constructor`. like this

```
public enum Status 
 { 
        STATUS_OPEN(0),  
        STATUS_STARTED(1),  
        STATUS_INPROGRESS(2),  
        STATUS_ONHOLD(3),  
        STATUS_COMPLETED(4),  
        STATUS_CLOSED(5); 

       private int status;

       private Status(int status){
        this.status = status;
       }

     public int getStatus(){
       return this.status;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: This is useless without a getter

Comment: I thought the OP can include :P, anyway i have included that.