# Add multiple elements to Object in Java

Tags: java, json, object, enums, timezone

I use the following map for enums and add an `enum` as shown below:

```
final Map<String, Object> enums = new HashMap<>();

enums.put("ZoneIds", gmtValues());
```

The `ZoneIds` enum has a `List<String>` returned from this method:

```
private static List<String> gmtValues() {
        return  ... // code omitted for brevity
    }


private static List<String> gmtNames() {
        return  ... // code omitted for brevity
    }
```

However, I want to pass another list in the same Object and then retrieve these 2 passed values in the frontend as `ZoneIds.value` and `ZoneIds.name`. So, how can I do this?

Comment: Put a list of lists? Or probably better, design your own class of objects holding the two lists.

Comment: I cannot change `final Map<String, Object> enums = new HashMap<>();`. So, how can I solve the problem without changing this?

Comment: Just like that. Your custom object holding the two lists will be a subclass of `Object`, so just like you can put a list into your map, you can also put your custom object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following options are possible:

- `"ZoneIds"` is a list of lists, with `name` and `value` properly ordered by index

```json
{"ZoneIds": [["name1", "value1"], ["nameN", "valueN"]]}
```

Then names/values are joined like this assuming that the sizes of lists returned by `gmtNames()` and `gmtValues()` are equal:

```java
List<String> names = gmtNames();
List<String> values = gmtValues();
List<List<String>> nameValueList = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(names.size(), values.size()))
    .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.asList(names.get(i), values.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
enums.put("ZoneIds", nameValueList);
```

---

- `"ZoneIds"` is a list of maps:

```json
{"ZoneIds": [{"name":"name1", "value":"value1"}, {"name":"nameN", "value":"valueN"}]}
```

```java
List<Map<String, String>> listMaps = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(names.size(), values.size()))
    .mapToObj(i -> Map.of("name", names.get(i), "value", values.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
enums.put("ZoneIds", listMaps);
```

---

- Simple map, with key taken from `gmtNames()` list:

```json
{"ZoneIds": {"name1":"value1", "nameN":"valueN"}}
```

```java
Map<String, String> nameValueMap = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(names.size(), values.size()))
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        names::get,    // key from names list
        values::get,   // value from values list
        (v1, v2) -> v1, // merge function in case of conflicts
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    ));
enums.put("ZoneIds", nameValueMap);
```